# Send email after creating user using Graph API in B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have below requirement:

1. We are creating B2C users (with random password) using Graph API from our Asp.Net Core Web API.

We want to send welcome email to the user along with some link so that user can directly launch the "Password Reset" page and then can login to his application after setting the password.

As per my research, Different Solutions and their cons:

1. User login and follow the forgot password journey from login but that's bit annoying for new users. How would they know that they have to follow forgot password journey on 1st login.
2. Implement "Forced to reset password on 1st Login" policy - but for this policy, user should know his initial password.
3. Using REST API - we can't use REST api in custom policy as we are creating user using Graph API.

Is there any better way to send email to user on creation(using graph API)?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Anu

Answer (score 0):

You can send out an "invite" link via email after creating the account via Graph API, which, when the user opens from their inbox, they can use it to set a new password at AAD B2C, and are immediately logged in to the app once completed (or you can do other things in the journey if you like).

This uses the `id_token_hint` concept demonstrated [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite).